# When to rturn Json data over simple Ado.Net data return?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

In Asp.Net MVC now more trend is returning Json data over simple returning of data in the *View*. 
Why returning of Json data is preferred?

Answer (score 1):

Here several facts that support your statement of preferring JSON over data.

1. It is much more helpful when working with client side scripting.
2. If you use ajax call json data is much more readable than class object.
3. Almost all browser supports it.
4. It is developer friendly.
5. Parsing complex data object to json is easier and convinient.